# Arduino code compiles both on Eclipse and on AVR Studio 5, but only Eclipse version is functional

Tags: arduino, avr, eclipse

I'm trying to choose an IDE for arduino development. I installed both Eclipse and AVR Studio 5. And configured them using the instruction on the Arduino site (for Eclipse) and those two tutorials ([AVR Freaks](http://www.engblaze.com/tutorial-using-avr-studio-5-with-arduino-projects), [EngBlaze](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=884538)) for the AVR Studio.

I've written a simple project in Eclipse. The code compiles and work as expected when uploaded to the Arduino (Atmega2560). I then used the same code and created an AVR Studio project.

On AVR Studio my code compiles just fine (so it seems) but when I upload it to the board (using the same avrdude configuration) the board only flashes the L led (pin 13) at a what seems like 1 second rate.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Sometimes IDEs have settings in them that change the fuses (what tells the chip the speed to run at among other things) regardless of what your code tells it to be. I have never used an arduino, but my guess is on that. I'll let someone who knows more answer though.

Answer (score -4):

AVR Studio uses the atmel compiler (IAR). What compiler does Eclipse use (I'm guessing gcc). There are differences in the extensions and in the standard libraries for different compilers.

Comment: Um, no.  AVR Studio uses avr-gcc.  IAR has compiler which is compatible with AVR processors, but it's not integrated with AVR Studio.